# left join done after 13 second on 7000 records - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `gps` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trucks_drivers_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `y` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `speed` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
```

number of my records is 7000.

my query is :

```
SELECT m1.*
            FROM gps m1 LEFT JOIN gps m2
             ON (m1.driver_id = m2.driver_id AND m1.id < m2.id)
            WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

but my result take too long time:

Showing rows 0 - 4 (5 total, Query took **13.1221 seconds**.)

why?!

someone tell me to use `index` to speed up your query. but I got syntax error:

```
SELECT m1.* FROM gps m1 LEFT JOIN gps m2 FORCE INDEX(m1.*) ON (m1.driver_id = m2.driver_id AND m1.id < m2.id) WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: do you have any indexes created?

Comment: @RadimBača (I think we know the answer to that!)

Comment: id is a PRIMARY KEY, right?

Comment: @Strawberry yes, it is PRIMARY key.

Comment: Please amend your table definition accordingly.

Comment: In schema `id` field is `NOT NULL` but in query you are using `m2.id IS NULL` ?

Comment: Does it make a difference in the speed of the queue?

Comment: It should make difference try this query - `SELECT m1.*
            FROM gps m1 LEFT JOIN gps m2
             ON (m1.driver_id = m2.driver_id)
            WHERE  m1.id < m2.id`

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM gps m1 LEFT JOIN
     gps m2
     ON m1.driver_id = m2.driver_id AND m1.id < m2.id
WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

You want an index on `gps(driver_id, id)`.  You need to create the index before you can use it:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_gps_driverid_id ON gps(driver_id, id);
```

Comment: My understanding was that including a PK in a composite key was unlikely to be of much benefit. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I run this first: `CREATE INDEX idx_gps_driverid_id ON gps(driver_id, id);` now I want to use my query it take  time about 4 seconds !

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I think MySQL includes a primary key in the index anyway as a way of referring back to the row in the table.  Nevertheless, I like to be explicit about why the index is being used, so I tend to include all the columns that I want.